# Automatically remove duplicate data when pasting into excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a set of CSV data copied from a grid in third party program that I want to paste into excel. The data consists of names in the first column and dates/times in the second column. The data is descending order of time and continually updated. The problem is that the grid for whatever reason has a limit of 1000 rows and as it belongs to s third party app, I can’t get the limit increased.

I want to be able to automatically remove duplicate rows based on the name column in the data set and keep the row with the oldest time. 
The trickier bit is that I will be continually adding to the excel grid so I need to also check against the existing data in excel and remove any duplicate rows from the data to be pasted.
I want to be able to do this automatically as I will not have enough time to quickly format it manually.

So is there a way to achieve this? 
Thanks,
iq

Comment: I think you can handle this easily with Power Query (Get & Transform) there you can connect directly your csv file and sort by date column and remove duplicates. Then it will be just a right click > refresh to get your new data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the original data is not in a csv file. It resides in a grid which constantly gets updated. I have to manually copy using ctrlC and paste into Excel using ctrlV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code into the worksheet's private code sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then
        On Error GoTo meh
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        With Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(2), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
            .Cells.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
        End With
    End If
meh:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This is triggered by 2 or more cells of data being pasted into the worksheet.

Comment: Thanks @Jeeped. That's awesome. Works very well.